# User Profile Pictures (FullPhotoUrl) not publicly accessible anymore

Tags: permissions, user, public

It is suddenly not possible for us to access the profile picture of a User (FullPhotoUrl) without being logged in. Trying to navigate to [https://___.file.force.com/profilephoto/[ID]/F](https://___.file.force.com/profilephoto/%5BID%5D/F) redirects me to a login page, instead of showing the image if I am not logged in.

If I am right this should be determined by the checkbox "Show my photo on publicly accessible pages" (field UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers) when editing a profile picture. However this does not change anything.

It seems we can also not make this work on other Orgs.

Are there any other checks that determine the permissions to open the image URL of profile pictures?

Edit:

This feature seems to not be available anymore for non-community users. We decided to use Documents instead.

Comment: where are you trying to access the URL in community or org?

Comment: I am trying to access the image on the URL (https:// ___.file.force.com/profilephoto/[ID]/F)  in an incognito window (so that I am not logged in to the Org)

Comment: @MukulMahawariya I understand this link looks like it is only for internal purposes, however we have been using this direct image URL for years now and it suddenly stopped working now. A misconfiguration by an admin on our side is plausible, however do you know if something has changed regarding accessing the image using the URL?

The link also does not seem to work on a Guest Profile on an Experience Builder page.

Comment: Ever make any progress on this? I'm trying to figure out the same thing right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by the field name, it's for internal Salesforce websites which are publicly available therefore you were not able to access it outside those websites.

You can see it in this article -
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_profile_photo.htm&type=5

[image]